# iOS 9.1 NSMutableArray Crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios9.1

We have a company salesapp that runs on a lot iPads. One device keeps crashing every now and then. The crashlog shows:

Model: iPad5,4
iOS: 9.1
Exeption:

> [__NSArrayM removeObjectsInArray:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x157d022a0

First of we don't use this method in our code. Testing with the 9.1 iOS Simulator shows that the method gets called by the os during touch events. It is also not an immutable object btw.

This didn't happen in previous versions and the codebase didn't change since the last update was content only.

However the only new component is XCode 8. The previous version was made with XCode 7.

Granted the user needs to update his iPad.(If IT will allow)
But that doesn't explain what is happening here.
No crashes before XCode 8 - wich sound troubling if XCode is the culprit.

Our logs shows that all other iPads run 8.3, 9.3.5 or 10.x.
Are there any issues known with iOS 9.1 that could explain this?

Comment: Post the code for the method. By Description it is hard to help.

Comment: We don't use this method. Thats is the problem.

Comment: Do you have any CocoaPods in the project that may?

Comment: Nope. No Cocoa pods. About 30 pads have no issues, just this one. Could imagine a firmware issue, but the pad (iPad Air 2) wasn't updated since 9.1 and all previous Apps did run fine. No codebase change, just XCode is new. I tend to suggest a Firmware upgrade, but it doesn't explain what went wrong. Especial since XCode is the only changed component.

Comment: did you update your xcode from 8.0 to 8.1, it may solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, I did. It looks very like an issue with XCode 8.x in general. However iOS 9.1 is the only affected version. As far I can tell it is the combination XCode 8 ObjC Code and iOS 9.1. That is very specific and uncommon.